# How to get more details flags from questions?

Tags: feature-request, api, api-v2.2, closing, flags

Short question:

**How to get the flags that led up to a question being closed?**

---

When we are going to flag a question, we have to look at [/questions/{id}/flags/options](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/question-flag-options) first, and I can see

The option `off-topic because… (too old to migrate)` has many sub-options, for example:

- Questions about general computing ...
- Questions on professional server- or networking...
- Questions asking us to recommend...
- Questions seeking debugging help...
- This question was caused by a problem that can no longer...
- Blatantly off-topic...

But when I [am querying on a question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#page=1&order=desc&sort=activity&ids=16574544&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), I can only get the `closed_reason`, that does not match any of the flag options for `duplicate` and has no more details about it. I tried messing up with the filters, but could not the flags that led up to a closing decision. How to get the flags that led up to a question being closed?

---

**EDIT**: Based on the comment, I tried to get the same information using data.stackexhange. You can see my [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/425802/flagger-test) here and the [API request](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=20882714&filter=!9YdnSH6-f&site=stackoverflow&run=true) here. I cannot seem to be able to get even the same information from the both sources, and cannot get the close votes...

Comment: Those kinds of flags don't close questions.  They are converted to close votes and those close the question.  Look into close votes. And not much detail is available for this in the API, IIRC.

Comment: @Brock, I tried to follow this idea, but could not fin anything, see my edit please. tks

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear; sorry.  I don't think you can get the information you seem to want.  You can get the general, final reason a question was closed and you can get a list of the users who voted to close the Q (but each not necessarily for the final reason).  That's it.  Any more is unlikely to ever be provided by SE.